# Check if there are different characters that are written once

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a small script that opens a file, gets it's size and writes the size of the file in zeros or ones depending on what is needed.

```
def firstDeletion(filepath, txt):
    multiplier = getSize(filepath)
    with open(filepath, "w") as text_file:
         text_file.write(multiplier * txt)
```

After that I want it to verify that there is only the given character in the file. The way I tried to do it is below, but I think my approach is wrong

```
def checkFile(file,phrase):
    with open(file, 'r') as resultfile:
        for line in resultfile:
            if (not phrase) in resultfile: #if found character different than phrase in resultfile
                return False
            else:
                return True  #No other char found
```

I think that it checks if my given character isn't at all in the text file instead of checking if there is another character also. I tried reading a character a time and check if they match, but I'm getting an error. And I don't like this method since I'm afraid that if I do just read in case a file is large (like 1 or 2GB the script will crash because of the memory)

```
def checkFile(file,char):
    letter = file.read(1)
    if letter == char:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The error i get is:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`

I'm completely new to python and it's a little bit messed up in my mind sorry.

Comment: So what is the actual question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a single character you are concerned about (not a word or a phrase that can be broken between two lines), then you were very close with your first attempt.

```
def checkFile(file,phrase):
    with open(file, 'r') as resultfile:
        for line in resultfile:
            if not all(char == phrase for char in line): # here you need to work with line, not the file object
                return False
            else:  # This else is redundant, because you can only return from a function once
                return True
```

I rewrote this using a generator expression and improved Python style. You were shadowing the built-in name `file` and violating several PEP8 recommendations.

```
def only_char_in_file(fp, target_char):
    with open(fp) as f:
        return all(char == target_char for line in f for char in line.strip())
```

**Update** Both methods above process files lazily (only a single line is read into memory). If your file contains a single huge line, then you need a special way to treat it. This method will work significantly slower then the former two, because it implies a lot more IO and low-level stuff works slower in Python than high-level abstractions (because the later actually run in C). Anyway:

```
import os


def only_char_in_file(fp, target_char):
    with open(fp) as f:
        char = f.read(1)
        while char:
            if char not in (target_char, os.linesep):
                return False
            char = f.read(1)
        return True
```

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that your method of iterating over the result_file line by line will also read the whole file into ram since the OP is writing only one line into the target file in the `firstDeletion` function

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know about the all command and also thanks for notifying me for the name file.

Comment: @EricDill my method lazily processes a file line by line. If it so happens that the file contains a single long line, then the only option is to go low-level and read bytes.

Comment: @EricDill I've added a one-char method.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for updating that to more fully answer the OPs question and use case

Answer (score 0):

```
def checkFile(file,phrase):
    with open(file, 'r') as resultfile:
        for line in resultfile:
            if (not phrase) in resultfile: #if found character different than phrase in resultfile
                return False
            else:
                return True  #No other char found
```

What's wrong with this function is the statement `if (not phrase) in resultfile` because the `not` keyword converts a boolean to its opposite. All empty strings are False and all other strings are True. Which means that in your if statement you're checking for a boolean in *resultfile*.

The reason you're getting an AttributeError in your other function is because you're passing a String when you should be passing a File object (*resultfile* is for example a File object).

I would write your function like this:

```
def check_file(file, phrase):
    with open(file, 'r') as result_file:
        for line in result_file.readlines():
            # Check that the line (with white space character removed) contains just 1 element
            # then check that the element is phrase.
            if len(set(line.strip())) == 1 and phrase in line:
                continue
            else:
                return False
    return True
```